# Getting Data from Firestore for web

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I currently try to use firebase for web and get data from Firestore.
This is my code for bring the all my data from Firestore.

```
function FireStoreGetAllData() {

let db = firebase.firestore();
let dataMap = new Map();

db.collection("User").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
          
            let dataset = new Map();
            let docId = doc.id;
            let docdata = doc.data();

            let firstName = docdata.first;
            let lastName = docdata.last;
            let bornData = docdata.born;

            dataset.set('first', firstName);
            dataset.set('last', lastName);
            dataset.set('born', bornData)

            dataMap.set(docId, dataset);
        });

    });
console.log('dataSet',dataMap.entries());
return dataMap;}
```

Problem is the "dataMap" always return null every time.
I debug this issue and find out that "db.colloction" is execute the code after "return dataMap".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.collection` is execute after `return dataMap` because of the **asynchronous**.

Make you `FireStoreGetAllData` as async function then you will get your dataMap.

```
async function FireStoreGetAllData() {

   let db = firebase.firestore();
   let dataMap = new Map();

   const querySnapshot = await db.collection("User").get();
   querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

        let dataset = new Map();
        let docId = doc.id;
        let docdata = doc.data();

        let firstName = docdata.first;
        let lastName = docdata.last;
        let bornData = docdata.born;

        dataset.set('first', firstName);
        dataset.set('last', lastName);
        dataset.set('born', bornData)

        dataMap.set(docId, dataset);
    });

    
   return dataMap;
}
```